# Adding a function to the array prototype

Tags: javascript, arrays

Why does adding this simple JavaScript function to the array prototype cause a significant slowdown in my animations?

NB To draw a single frame does use a lot of arrays. Is adding your own functions to the Array prototype *that* significant?

```
Array.prototype.last = function()
{
    return this[this.length - 1];
};
```

Comment: I _think_ it is unlikely that this alone cripples your performance. You should describe what your animation does and how and when it runs. Finally it is generally frowned upon to extend the prototype of native types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer assumes that the code has been profiled and the bottleneck identified here. If this is not the case, please do that first: [Chrome](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/12/devtools-javascript-cpu-profile-migration) | [Firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Performance/Profiling_with_the_Built-in_Profiler) | [Edge](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/devtools-guide/performance)

The tips below focus on V8-specific optimization, but typically improve performance on other engines as well.

---

While functionally equivalent, I'd suggest making two changes to `last()`:

- It should be a static method accepting an array as a parameter, not a member method of `Array`.
- It should [avoid out-of-bounds access](https://v8.dev/blog/elements-kinds#avoid-reading-beyond-the-length-of-the-array).

With that in mind, try this:

```
function last (array) {
  var lastIndex = array.length - 1;
  if (lastIndex === -1) return undefined;
  return array[lastIndex];
}
```

At this point, you might be thinking

> Cool, now I can re-use this for array-*like* objects such as `arguments`.

If you [avoid generic usage](https://v8.dev/blog/elements-kinds#prefer-arrays-over-array-like-objects), then the function can stay optimized, otherwise the optimizer has to bail out and use less efficient abstractions in order to allow types other than `Array` as input.

Comment: Interesting. Your function doesn't cause a slowdown.

Comment: As for me, I am generally unwilling to "extend" language-generic things such as Arrays.  Just give me a nice *function,* like the one shown above.